# CORs rule not found when putting data in azure storage

Tags: ajax, cors, azure-storage

So I have a site where I upload large video files using html 5 to azure storage using an sas signature.  It seems to work fine on most systems and browsers but doesn't seem to work on iPhones.  I finally routed the call through fiddler via proxy and got the response from the storage server.

[image]

Here is the CORs rule I have set up.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: The allowed methods for your CORS Rule doesn't have 'OPTIONS', which based on your fiddler that is the method you are using.

Comment: @JacobRoberts that could be it, but I do doubt it. Worth trying.. but the pre-flight request does not validate itself. The OPTION request (the pre-flight) hits the server, and says "Hey, I have a request coming in, cross-origin.. will you allow it? It's a 'PUT' request" and the server says "Sure, I allow 'PUT' requests from that origin". I don't think it validates the pre-flight, OPTION request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good evening,

There are a few things I would like you to try simultaneously, when you get a chance:
1. Change your Allowed Headers to: "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,Accept-Language,Content-Language,Last-Event-ID,X-HTTP-Method-Override, x-ms-*". NOTE: You may not need all of these, but for now, add them all to see if we can get it working.
2. Change your Allowed Methods to: NONE, PUT, OPTIONS
3. Set the Max Age (seconds) field to 0
4. Create another rule, and do not have a comma-separated list of allowed origins. Make a separate rule for each origin. (I've heard of certain browsers not liking the CSV).

Once all is said and done, if the above does not work, try removing "Authorization" from the allowed headers since it looks like you are not using that (but first, try it with it).

Please let me know if you make any progress with the above ideas.